# Sql Query, Select distinct rows where not null

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a question:

So I have the following data in a table"

```
id        name     city     state      phone         price

234    Kevin    Chicago   IL        5555555555    550

234    Kevin    Chicago   IL        5555555555    NULL

234    Kevin    Chicago   IL        55555    NULL

234    Kevin    Chicago   IL        NULL    NULL
```

People have loaded data into a database and it is showing up like this because of character restrictions for each line...

So how can I tell my distinct query to get the most from each one..I just want this row returned:

```
234    Kevin    Chicago   IL        5555555555    550
```

And I cant do "where all rows are not null etc" because the last row can always be null too it depends.

Thanks a  lot of your help!

Comment: what is your query right now?

Comment: Look up some tutorial, this is way to basic to look out for help.

Comment: Can you provide the table layout? Your example doesn't provide a logical primary key, surrogate key, or anything that would help indicate the most recent record. (e.g. Row_Insert_Timestamp) Is there some more business logic that tells you the most recent record is the one with the fewest NULL values? (e.g. The most complete record for a given ID.)

Comment: I have tried : "select distinct id, name, city, state, max(phone), max(price)" to no avail. I have also tried a bunch of group by's and couldnt get it to work...

Comment: There is no lastmodifieddate, or key that will indicate to us what the most recent record is or which record has the most information. I know the data is messed up but I have to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what "the most" means exactly and depending on the data types of `phone` and `price`,  this could be your query:

Edit: generalize query, get `phone` & `price` per person.

```
SELECT id, name, city, state, max(phone) AS phone, max(price) AS price
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY id, name, city, state;
```

`phone` and `price` can come from different rows this way.

The manual on [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html):

> Unless otherwise stated, group functions ignore NULL values.

So, `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` are not required here.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT 
ID, 
MAX (IFNULL (NAME, ' ')) AS NAME, 
MAX (IFNULL (CITY, ' ')) AS CITY, 
MAX (IFNULL (STATE, ' ')) AS STATE, 
MAX (IFNULL (PHONE, ' ')) AS PHONE, 
MAX (IFNULL (PRICE, ' ')) AS PRICE
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY ID
```

The above gives you for each the "max" of each column - this can lead to content from different rows being combined...